# Assigning "parent" color palettes in R

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I'm working on creating a map using Leaflet. You'll notice in the first step, I break out each county into four different "regions". I then join it on another geo file of smaller territories within each customized "region." What if I wanted each region to have a different color palette? So let's say:

1 = red

2 = blue

3 = green

4 = orange

So now, not only will each region be colored in accordance to its assigned color, but the "districts" within those regions would also take on that color, and the fill value will also populate as such based as a weight.

```
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

ct_counties <- tigris::counties("Connecticut") %>% st_as_sf() %>% mutate(region = case_when(COUNTYFP %in% c('001','005') ~ 1,
                                                                                  COUNTYFP %in% c('009','003') ~ 2,
                                                                                  COUNTYFP %in% c('007','013') ~ 3,
                                                                                  COUNTYFP %in% c('011','015') ~ 4))

ct_districts <- tigris::voting_districts("Connecticut") %>% st_as_sf()

ct_all <- ct_districts %>% st_join(ct_counties, by = "COUNTYFP10") %>% mutate(pop = sample(1000:10000, n(), replace = TRUE))


bins <- c(0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, Inf)
pal <- colorBin("red", domain = ct_all$pop, bins = bins)

leaflet(ct_all) %>% addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(pop),
                                weight = 4,
                                opacity = 1,
                                color = "white",
                                dashArray = "3",
                                fillOpacity = 0.7)
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly, but why not use `pal <- colorBin(c("red", "blue", "green", "orange"), domain = ct_all$region)` and `~pal(region)`.

Comment: Are you saying that, for each of the four regions, you want to have separated color palettes?